# C# Generic Error GDI+ on SaveAdd

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, tiff

I'm trying to create a small program to take a set of multi-page TIFF files from a folder, remove the front page and save the remaining pages using the same name to a separate output folder.

The files can save to the output folder without issue but I get "A Generic Error Occurred in GDI+" when it gets to the SaveAdd function on the **second** document. The first document(7 pages on output) adds all pages correctly. The second document fails when trying to add additional pages/frames after the initial page. I've tried different documents as first and second with varying number of pages. Can anyone shed any light on the issue?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;

namespace FrontPageRemover
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Image frame;
            int pages;
            string fileName;

            string folderPath = @"TIFF\Tiff Files";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath);
            Image image;

            Encoder encoder = Encoder.SaveFlag;
            ImageCodecInfo encoderInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(i => i.MimeType == "image/tiff");
            EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                image = Image.FromFile(file);
                pages = image.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);
                image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, 1);

                fileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
                image.Save(@"TIFF\Files Out\" + fileName, encoderInfo, encoderParams);

                for (int index = 2; index < pages; index++)
                {
                    image.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, index);
                    encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.FrameDimensionPage);
                    image.SaveAdd(encoderParams);                     
                }

                encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.Flush);
                image.SaveAdd(encoderParams);
                image.Dispose();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `EncoderParameter` class implements `IDisposable`, and therefore should be disposed. Your code leaks it. Consider using `using` blocks to save yourself from having to sprinkle calls to `Dispose` throughout. There may be other objects that need to be disposed, too. Check your code carefully for leaks. For what it's worth, you *always* get this error message when there's an error in GDI+, and the `System.Drawing` namespace is a big wrapper around GDI+.

Comment: Managed to solve it. Un-ticking the "prefer 32-bit" checkbox didn't fix so it re-iterated what i had already assumed that something wasn't clearing or triggering within the loop. I started reading up on IDispose(I'm self taught so every time I code I need to look at least 1 thing up!) and realised I was setting Param outside the loop. Putting it inside fixed the issue. Thanks for the pointers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments pointed me in the right direction with regards to the EncoderParameters not updating/being disposed of correctly.

The issue was with

```
encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(encoder, (long)EncoderValue.MultiFrame);
```

being outside of the loop. Hence the first document working correctly but the second document failing.